# Get Count and Distinct items with LINQ query?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

We have below SQL tables :

```
Tag
----------------------------------------
ID  |   tagName     |   UserID
----------------------------------------
01  |   c++         |   03
02  |   c#          |   03
03  |   asp.net     |   04
04  |   programming |   05
05  |   vb          |   07
06  |   php         |   07
07  |   java        |   12
08  |   class       |   12

TagRelation
----------------------------------------
ID  |   tagID   |   topicID
----------------------------------------
01  |   01      |   22
02  |   02      |   22
03  |   08      |   22
04  |   06      |   12
05  |   02      |   12
06  |   04      |   104
07  |   02      |   104
08  |   01      |   104
09  |   02      |   17
10  |   05      |   17
```

now I want to get the number of repeating each tags in `TagRelation` table for each users with LINQ query.
I've used the following query , but it doesn't compile, it has some errors.

```
DataClassesDataContext dbc = new DataClassesDataContext();
var query = from q in dbc.Tags
            where q.UserID == this.UserID
            from c in dbc.TagRelations
            where c.tagID == q.id
            select new
            {
                tagName = q.name.Distinct(),
                repeatNumber = c.Count()
            };
```

How can I do it? Thanks.

**Edit:** Actually I expected the following result:

```
result (if UserID==3)

-------------------------
tagName |   repeatNumber
-------------------------
c++     |   02
c#      |   01
```

Comment: You can use group by for achieving the desired result

Comment: Could you please post a sample code, I don't familiar with `group by`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var q = ...
        group r by r.TagName into g;
        select new
        {
            TagName = g.Key,
            Count = g.Count()
        };

foreach (var i in q)
{
    string tagName = i.TagName;
    int count = i.Count;    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from t in dbc.Tags
where t.UserID == this.UserID
join r in dbc.TagRelations on t.id equals r.tagID
group r by t into g
select new
{
    tagName = g.Key.name,
    repeatNumber = g.Count()
};
```

Comment: `group by` just by `r` will not give the desired result, will it?

Comment: @abatishchev, I'm grouping by `t` and it will give the desired result with LINQ to Objects and I was hoping it will do the same with LINQ to SQL.

Comment: my test shows that `new[] { new Tag { TagName="c#" }, new Tag { TagName="c#" } }.GroupBy(t => t)` groups by reference, i.e. each tag in separate tag.

Comment: @abatishchev, yes, in LINQ to Objects, it uses the default equality comparer. I'm assuming that the equality is taken care of, either by overriding `Equals()` (and `GetHashCode()`) or by having only one instance for each tag name, in which case reference equality works correctly.